# Pointer to template method gives <unresolved overloaded function type>)

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, function-pointers

I've read numerous questions of those with similar problems, but most of the time they boil down to people using function pointers instead of method pointers, or omitting the class scope when creating the pointer instance.  However I'm doing neither of those (I think...):

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() { mFuncPtrs.insert( 10, &Test::Func<int> ); } // Error!

    template <class T>
    void Func() {}

private:
    typedef void ( Test::*FuncPtr )();
    std::map<int, FuncPtr> mFuncPtrs;
};
```

But this gives:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<int, void (Test::*)(), std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, void (Test::*)()> > >::insert(int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

But I'm being explicit with the template type, providing the full scope of the method, and `Func()` has no overloads!  If it makes any difference I'm using g++ v4.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `insert()` function of `std::map` wrongly. There is no overload of `insert()` that takes a key and a value as two separate arguments.

Instead, you need to call it on a `std::pair` of key and value:

```
mFuncPtrs.insert(std::make_pair(10, &Test::Func<int>) );
```

Or, in C++11, you can use uniform initialization syntax for the pair:

```
mFuncPtrs.insert( { 10 , &Test::Func<int> } );
```

---

Simplest of all, though, would be to avoid `insert()` altogether and just use the index operator:

```
mFuncPtrs[10] = &Test::Func<int>;
```

---

Even better, given that all of this happens in the constructor, i.e. at intialization time for the map, again in C++11, you can *initialize* the map with the pair(s) you want:

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test()
    : mFuncPtrs { { 10 , &Test::Func<int> } }
  { }

  /* ... */
};
```

Comment: +1 Good god... This is what happens when you use Qt for too long.  Thank you!